# Laravel 5 view not found when using vagrant and homestead

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, laravel-5, homestead

**UPDATE START**

Instead of using `return view('welcome');` I now used `return 'woo. It works.'` which made it work. So it seems like the view pathes configured incorrectly. Does someone know if I could be right with my assumption? 'Cause the stacktrace of the error says something along the lines

> at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('welcome', array('/Users/mknb/work/API/testproject/resources/views'))

But shouldn't it say `/home/vagrant/testproject/resources/views` ?

**UPDATE END**

---

I'm using Laravel since a few weeks or months now and now wanted to also use Laravel together with Homestead. The problem I'm having now, is, after editing my `Homestead.yaml`,the `/etc/hosts` and starting vagrant `vagrant up` I'm getting the error

> InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
>   View [welcome] not found.

When using the exact same project without Homestead/Vagrant but with Virtual Hosts instead, I'm having no problems. So what could cause this?

This is my `Homestead.yaml`

---

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
hostname: testproject
name: testproject
provider: virtualbox

authorize: /Users/mknb/.ssh/id_homestead.pub

keys:
    - /Users/mknb/.ssh/id_homestead

folders:
    - map: "/Users/mknb/work/API/testproject"
      to: "/home/vagrant/testproject"

sites:
    - map: testproject.app
      to: "/home/vagrant/testproject/public"

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

And this is the `/etc/hosts`

`192.168.10.10 testproject.app`

Well, at least it seems to work, that the server has been started, etc. but why am I getting this error? I also tried to clear my config cache and route cache with the following two commands

`php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan:route:cache`

Line 2 of the stacktrace looks like this

```
at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('welcome', array('/Users/mknb/work/API/testproject/resources/views')) in FileViewFinder.php line 79
```

But shouldn't my vagrant path be set here? Can this be the problem?

Comment: Seems like its an issue with the path for welcome view. what is the file name for welcome view?

Comment: your hosts file mentions socialpersons.app and your homestead mentions testproject.app?

Comment: Sorry Luceos. Haha, was the wrong entry of the host file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue.

I connected to my vagrant box with `vagrant ssh` and afterwards navigated to my testproject `cd testproject` and ran the command to regenerate the config with `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: This Saved my day . 2 days of googling , i did php artisan config:cache million times but not with ssh (server) .. i don`t know why it is working with ssh .. but any way ,thx

Comment: i have same problem - my prjoect path is c:Project\Laravel and my default homestead path is c:/user/pravin/homestead where to use `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

check your folder name(pathname error)

**example**-  `return view('Country.add');
          return view('country.add');`